# Import a value from an excel sheet and use that value in xpath

Tags: java, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I'm working on selenium webdriver with java. I need to import a value from an excel sheet and use that value for xpath.
I tried the following code:

```
WebElement firstRound = driver.findElement(By.xpath(getCellContent(3,rowNumber)));
firstRound.click();
```

But it returned the error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find elements when the XPath expression is null.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Please provide the code for `getCellContent`

Comment: public String getCellContent(int columnNumber, int rowNumber)
 {
  return excelSheet.getCell(columnNumber, rowNumber).getContents();
 }

Answer (score 0):

Verify the return value of:

```
getCellContent(3,rowNumber)
```

By looking at the error I feel the above statement is returning null.